# Pyqt4 age calculator does not output on label

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, calculator

My python/QT (Pyqt4) program is supposed to output a person's age after the calculate button has been pressed, but it doesnt, where have I gone wrong. My code and screenshot of the program when running is hereby attached.
my python code that does not display the text in a label.

this is my .pyw file

```
import sys
from ass2q2 import *

class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.calculateBtn, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.dispmessage)

    def dispmessage(self):
        bd=(self.ui.calBD.selectedDate())
        curr= QDate.currentDate()
        yourAge = bd.daysTo(curr)        
        self.ui.labelOutput.setText("Your Age (in days) is: " +yourAge.toString())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

ass2q2.py file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ass2q2.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(705, 531)
        self.calBD = QtGui.QCalendarWidget(Dialog)
        self.calBD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 150, 280, 155))
        self.calBD.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("calBD"))
        self.calCurr = QtGui.QCalendarWidget(Dialog)
        self.calCurr.setEnabled(False)
        self.calCurr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 150, 280, 155))
        self.calCurr.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("calCurr"))
        self.labelbirth = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelbirth.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 120, 271, 16))
        self.labelbirth.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelbirth"))
        self.labelToDate = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelToDate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 120, 261, 21))
        self.labelToDate.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelToDate"))
        self.labelOutput = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelOutput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 340, 581, 41))
        self.labelOutput.setLineWidth(3)
        self.labelOutput.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.labelOutput.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelOutput"))
        self.calculateBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.calculateBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 460, 141, 51))
        self.calculateBtn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("calculateBtn"))
        self.labelApp = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelApp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 60, 411, 41))
        self.labelApp.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelApp"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.labelbirth.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">Select the Birth Date</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.labelToDate.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">Current Date</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.calculateBtn.setText(_translate("Dialog", "C A L C U L A T E", None))
        self.labelApp.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\">AGE (in days) CALCULATOR</span></p></body></html>", None))
```

[image: enter imsdfage description here]

Comment: read [ask], review the [tour] and show your code as text

Comment: Can you list whole ass2q2.py file as well? I would like to help you, but don't have enough of time to try typing this file manually into my editor.

Comment: Thanks... I have listed ass2q2.py as well

Comment: @SithembisoMkhize When you run your code in IDLE it will show you error messages in the shell window that explain what is wrong with your code. In this case, it will show an error like this: "NameError: name 'QDate' is not defined". Once you fix that and re-run the code, you will then get an error like this: "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'toString'". And once you fix that, the code should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro but it is not showing any error and does run, as per screenshot, but does not show anything on the labelOutput... Thanks for the suggestions, I will add those fixes too

Comment: @SithembisoMkhize 1. add `from PyQt4 import QtCore` on .pyw

Comment: @SithembisoMkhize 2. change `curr= QDate.currentDate()` to `curr= QtCore.QDate.currentDate()`

Comment: @SithembisoMkhize 3. change `self.ui.labelOutput.setText("Your Age (in days) is: " +yourAge.toString())` to `self.ui.labelOutput.setText("Your Age (in days) is:{}".format(yourAge))`

Comment: @SithembisoMkhize Yes, it certainly will show those errors after you click the "Calculate" button.

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys.... these 2 changes got it working "change self.ui.labelOutput.setText("Your Age (in days) is: " +yourAge.toString()) to self.ui.labelOutput.setText("Your Age (in days) is:{}".format(yourAge)) "